# Should I use a public pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am currently working on a game where I have a couple of classes which each handles their own gameobjects. For these classes to actually represent something in the game they need to use another class which is the animation_manager. 
The animation_manager handles the loading, drawing and moving of objects on the screen and is created at startup.

What would be the smartest way of passing the manager to the classes which handles the gameobjects?

Should it be done by a public pointer, by assigning it to a static pointer in the object class which every gameobject inherits from or should I simply just pass it as a pointer to the gameobjects/objects class constructor?

I am using C++03 so no new fancy fixes :P

**EDIT 1:**

There has been a lot of good suggestions and I am thankful for that. 
Now I will not use weak pointers since I dont need the object handlers to take care of the deletion of the pointer as its going to exist from the beginning to the end of the program. 
Singletons wont fit my needs either as I dont want any class to have access to it.

One thing that came to mind when reading the replies is: Would it be a good idea to make a `static reference` for the `anim_handler` in the `Object class` which all the handling classes inherits from?

Comment: The problem with a static reference is that it must be "statically" initialized and, being a reference, it can only be initialized to reference an already defined object. So, if you will not be able to instantiate your anim_handler object using "new", for example, and you would probably end having a very tight and quite uncomfortable bound between your ancestor class and a concrete object. You can overcome this limit by using a pointer, but then any object could perform a "delete" on that pointer, or just modify it. If you're going that route I would suggest using smart pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there are no explicit answer for this question, but rather multiple ways of doing it which each has their own opinion on.
In case anyone else have the same question I am going to list them below:

**Shared_Pointer:**
This method will keep track of the amount of used pointers pointing to the address and if that count hits zero, then it will deallocate the memory. Is available in C++11 and the boost library. 
A shared pointer can be passed to other objects the same way as a normal pointer.

*Suggested by ogni42*

**Passed by constructor:**
A pointer or reference can be passed to the object when it is being constructed. The upside of using a reference is that the programmer can't accidentally use `delete` on the pointer.

*Prefered by Onur.*

**Use of singletons**
`Singletons` are an unique extern class which holds a pointer to the object which can be accessed through a function.

*This was suggested by Albert*

**Global variables**
Simply a globally declared variables. Personally I do not recommend these as they can become a mess as they become available even from code which you wont need them in.

*Suggested by Sir PanCake*

**static variables**
This is what I ended up using. I made it so that only objects which inherited from my `Object` class could access the anim_handler. The way I did this was by declaring `Object` a friend of my anim_handler and then I made the static variable to retrieve the handler `protected`

Anyways, thanks for the support everyone! I appreciates it a lot and I even learned something new! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this shared manager object in a shared pointer which is added to C++11 (or you can use Boost library) standard as [shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).

It has a reference counting mechanism such that you do not have to worry about the ownership and memory management of related object.

Every `gameobject` can keep a shared pointer member to your `animation_manager`.

Comment: Im sorry. I should have mentioned that I began to write this before C++11 came out. I'm still using C++03. 
Speaking of memory management I got that under control. Every objecthandler will be deleted BEFORE the deconstruction of the animation_manger.

Comment: It might be worth it to also take a look at `weak_ptr`. This way, managers don't hold true references and can properly react to the case that the object has been destroyed. This may allow a more natural ownership management.

Comment: @Hjorthenify, it is also in Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the passing by constructor.

This way you can establish an invariant (i.e. the manager is always present) whereas later setting a field does not ensure it's always done.

Like thomas just posted you should use a `shared_ptr` or something similar (if not using C++11).

I try not to use static fields (except for constants) since it prevents you to use different manager objects for each gameobject. (Think of a debugging/logging manager class, or another  wrapped manager).

Comment: Well the manager will stay the same for all classes and is not going to change during runtime so wouldn't it somehow be smarter just to keep a single pointer shared by a class wide scope? 
As for `shared_ptr` are they really necessary?

Comment: What you're talking about is a static pointer that could be added to the ancestor class for all of your gameobjects handling classes. Still you would find some sort of "nice" way to initialize it, and to avoid any of the objects to modify it. If I understand your case correctly I would go for the singleton pattern as I wrote in my answer: better not letting the user objects the freedom of modifiying the reference to the animation_manager at all...

Comment: Globally accessible Singletons are bad, like all globally accessible noon-constants are. Like I stated in my answer: How would implement a "special" manager for some gameobjects? Have a look at these articles to understand why one should avoid global accessible singletons: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/.

Comment: Well, in my opinion a globally accessible singleton would be "less bad" than a static pointer which could be modified by any of the objects in the program. It would be a much less error prone solution. I'm not used to consider a particular pattern or solution "absolutely" bad or "absolutely" good, I just see things that fits and things that doesn't fit a particular use case.

Comment: Both static and global singleton are bad. Why choose the "less bad" when you can have a good solution? Pass what you need for a class in the constructor and you're fine.

Comment: Well, this would be good if the manager if passed by refence to the constructor and stored in a private reference member. Passing a pointer would allow some object to do a delete on that pointer, so it's not an option, in my opinion. But what if the "game manager" or something similar would like to change the animation_manager object? Should it destroy and create every gameobject? I don't find it practical, maybe it could look "good" at first sight, but it has its limits.

Comment: How the manager is stored and whether it should be `const` is another story. Hard to tell without knowing the project. But I suppose it's not likely the gameobjects will change their manager.

Answer (score 0):

If your animator_manager is a unique object, another approach could be defining it as a signleton, eventually removing the need for storing any reference to it in the gameobjects handling classes and using some sort of static method like animation_manager::getInstance() to use it.

The performance impact could be easily minimized by reducing the calls to the getInstance() method, but it really depends on your design, can't be sure it would fit.

Comment: What would be a performance impact in using singletons? The increased amount of function calls or what?

Comment: Well, I would talk about ONE singleton (if you're going to need more than one I would suggest to change strategy). Anyway, it really depends: performance impact could be negligible if calls to an hypothetical animation_manager::getInstance() are kept down to the necessary (one would simply cache the returned valued). If your animation_manager is one object serving all the objects in your application and if you think that you're never going to need more instances of it, I believe that it could fit.

Comment: There will never be more than one instance of the manager. Singletons would be a solution, but is it possible to make only the classes which inherits from `object` able to access it? I dont want any class which shouldnt be able to load animations able to do so.

Comment: A singleton is basically a globally accessible instance of a class. Who is aware of the class can access that object, you could work out a more sophisticated design but... Of course I don't know anything about your engine's architecture, but did you ever thought about "reversing" the perspective? I mean: maintaining a structure (tree, list, whatever) of gameobjects (all of them instances of classes derived by the same ancestor, maybe) and having your animation_manager object walk trough that structure and perform the needed animations? To me it would sound like a better solution.

Comment: That wouldnt be smart in my opinion.  What about the objects which doesnt need any animating such as funiture or walls? What i want to donis to allow the object to que the animhandler to either move an object, change its state or flag it to constantly change its state with a delay to add some animation. This is a 2D project btw.

Comment: As for singletons, they might be tje solution. I will try it out as soon as i get off work.

Answer (score 0):

you should give it as a reference (if possible a reference to a const), not a pointer. Only if you would have a class hierarchy of animation managers a pointer (if possible const to a const) would make sense. In the latter case, you should consider using boost's `shared_ptr`. If move to C++11 later, the changes to C++11's shared_ptr are minimal.

From the design point of view, you might also think about using an observer pattern, so the animation manager can decide on its own when it is the right time to render without having too much boilerplate code.

Comment: I like the idea of using references, but shared_ptr seems a bit excessive to use for my needs.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` barely has overhead when accessing, but relieves you from managing deallocation and reference counting. Since boost/C++11 I avoid raw pointers whenever I can, and I can avoid them nearly always except for some legact libraries.

Comment: How would i program a shared_ptr without using boost? I mean how would i add access to the underlying ptr without allowing to use the delete keyword on it?

Comment: you can access the underlying pointer via `shared_ptr<>::get()`

Comment: If o were tp make my own shared pointer template, then how would i make people able to access the pointers content, but not delete or modify it?

Comment: you could return a const pointer to a const, if that is sufficient. Still it would inhibit proper reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference would be the most favorable way when thinking as a good software architect, because it will allow easier testing and mocking.

However, a game(engine) is - in my opinion - such a special case of software where "good patterns" can be counterproductive sometimes. You will nearly always end up in the situation that you need some manager classes everywhere.

You might want to look at the god-object anti-pattern, to make all common managers available globally. I use one(!) globally accessible instance of an "Application"-instance, which contains some bootstrapping code and references to the most common manager classes, like this:

```
// application.h
class CApplication {
    void init(int argc, char **argv); // init managers & co here 
    void shutdown();
    void run();

    CMemoryManager * memory;
    CSystemManager * system;
    CAudioManager  * sound;
    CInputManager  * input;
};

// globals.h
CApplication * app;


// main.c
#include "globals.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    app = new CApplication();
    app->init(argc, argv);
    app->run();
    app->shutdown();
    return 0;
}

// some_other_file.cpp
#include "globals.h"

void doSomething() {
    // ...
    app->input->keyDown(...);
    // ...
}
```

Bad style? Probably. Does it work? For me it does. Feedback is also welcome as comment!

Comment: I don't think it could be defined as bad style or a bad solution. Most complex applications are based on some sort of big context and subsystems managing object, simply because the implemented functionality is based on very tight relationships between subsystems. Many times designers tends to put a lot of effort trying to achieve isolation between software subsystems, just to realize that with so much isolation the system simply can't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer because it's quite a different approach, when compared with the previuos one.
First of all I should clarify that I'm not experienced in game programming! :)
Anyway, as I was suggesting in my previous comments, maybe, I would take a different route. Immagine that you have a "game field" with walls and other static elemnts, and a number of "actors", like monsters, the player alter ego and so on...
I would probably write an ancestor "Actor", subcalssing "Player" and "Enemy" classes, then subclassing "Enemy" into "Dragon", "Zombie", "Crocodile" and so on. Maybe Actor could have a bounch of common attributes, like "location", "speed", "strenght", "energy", "direction", "destination" and a status, say "moving", "sleeping", "eating the player", "being eated"...
A typical game iteration, could be something like:

1) get input from the player

2) call a method of the player actor object, something like:

```
player->move(east, fast);
```

3) cycle trough a list of actors to update their status, say:

```
for (int i(0); i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    // Checks the player position in the gamefield and setup a strategy to eat him
    enemies[i]->updateStatus(player, gamingField);
}
```

4) cycle trough the list of actors and move them:

```
animator->animate(player);
for (int i(0); i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    animator->animate(enemies[i]);
}
```

5) check if something interesting has happened (the player has been eaten by the crocodile)

I mean: this is a totally different approach, but I think that isolating the actors logic could be a good idea, and you could avoid the original problem completely.

Comment: That is actually somewhat the same way i want to do it, but instead of looping through all of them i want to add them tp a quoue(think of windows message handler) which the anim handler then uses to find the ones needing an update.